# How to get user role name, when role update in discord using webhook

Tags: webhooks, discord, discord.net

I need help to get the user role when updated on discord.
I want this role using web-hook.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is `DiscordSocketClient#UserUpdated` which returns two `SocketUser`'s - one before and one after where you can then find what changed and get the new roles name.

You'd obviously have to compare what got changed as this event will also fire when a nickname is updated and so forth therefore you will have to compare the roles of the `before` and `after` `SocketUser`.